Is my choice between the simple past and past pefrect tense correct here?
I made up these sentences and I am wondering if I made a correct choice.
Example 1
Few commanders in the 18th century ordered their soldiers to charge at the enemy right at the beginning of a battle. Flintlock rifles were much more efficient than older gunpowder weapons. If the soldiers charged directly at the enemy lines with bayonets, they would be instantly killed by the enemy’s powerful firearms.
I use "charged" and "would be" for example 1 because according to the context, charging toward the enemy directly at the beginning of the battle was not common but still existed at that time.
Example 2
No commanders in the 18th century ordered their soldiers to charge at the enemy right at the beginning of a battle. Flintlock rifles were much more efficient than older gunpowder weapons. If the soldiers had charged directly at the enemy lines with bayonets, they would have been instantly killed by the enemy’s powerful firearms.
I use "had charged" and "would have been" for example 2 because according to the context, charging toward the enemy directly at the beginning of the battle didn't exist anymore at that time, and using a type 3 conditional would be better for the counter-fact hypothesis.
Am I right about my choice and explanation above?

Your explanations are good, but there is no reason that either pair could not work in either example. "Few commanders" is close to "no commanders," just a more understated way of writing.
